# Scala, importing my package

Tags: scala

This should be very simple, but for the life of me I can't find how to do it in Scala.

I define a package like:

```
package myown.utils
{
    class  Test {
        def showMe(n: Int) = {
                print(n)
        }
    }
}
```

Now if I import myown.utils, I have to write Test.showMe

How can I make "showMe" visible as a function that I can use directly without pre-pending the name of the class first? I know it is possible because that's what happens when I import some packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you don't understand the difference between an `object` and a `class`

```
package myown.utils
object  Test {
  def showMe(n: Int) = {
    print(n)
  }
}
```

You can now:

```
import myown.utils.Test._
```

An `object` is a singleton, a global instance of the `Test` class. With a normal `class`, you obviously have to instantiate it before you can use the methods.

Comment: Great, thanks ! and yeah it should be an object sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can create a package object:

```
package myown
{
    package object utils {
        def showMe(n: Int) = {
                print(n)
        }
    }
}
```

and `import myown.utils._`

Comment: What? What is the problem with it? Please see http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html

Comment: Perhaps you should read it yourself. The whole point of a package object is not having to import. Otherwise how is it different than a normal object?

Comment: Ah, edited. Oh, come on. Just was a small typo... Don't understand the downvote, but anyway...

Comment: How is that different than the other answer? I see they achieve the same result. Both cases, I can import myown.utils._

Comment: In both cases you can import `myown.utils._`, but in the response by flavian you have to call the function as `Test.showMe()`

Comment: @DiegoSevilla When you use a package object correctly, all sub-packages of the package will be aware of the type aliases defined in it and you won't be required to manually import anything.

It's the same feature the Scala library uses to always bring `scala.collection.immutable.Map` into scope for instance.